# ESP-01S + Fastled

Tags: esp8266, led-strip

I am trying to control a WS2812B Led Strip with my ESP-01S board.
It works fine with my ESP32 DevKit board, but the ESP-01S won't do anything :/
I couldn't figure out which 2 GPIO the ESP-01S is using (from the pinout), I assume it's GPIO0 (pin 5) and GPUI1 (pin 2).
I modified the sketch and tried several pin settings but the LED won't react.
any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: io 0 and io 2 are on every esp-01 header

Comment: and io 1 and io 3 as RX and TX. and io 0 has pull-up on esp-01s